# error in the setTimeout function returned Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, prestashop-1.6

I'm working with Prestashop 1.6 and I have a javascript file in the path, `theme/mytheme/js/autoload/shopflores.js` which returns an error. code:

```js
setTimeout(
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: urlformChx,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    data: {
      ajax: true,
      token: token,
      idcart: idCart,
      method: 'getCurrentShop'
    },
    success: function(resultx) {
      console.log(resultx);
      obj = JSON.parse(resultx);
      r = obj.region;

      if (obj.code == '200' && r != null) {
        $('#order-opc #uniform-regshopflores > span').text(obj.region);
        $("#regshopflores option").each(function() {
          if ($(this).text() == obj.region) {
            $(this).attr('selected', true);
          }
        });

        $('#order-opc .delivery_option_radio').parent('span').removeClass('checked');
        $('#order-opc .delivery_option_radio').removeAttr("checked");

        $('#uniform-seltiendaflores > span').text(obj.tienda);
        $("#seltiendaflores option").text(obj.tienda);

        $.each($("input.delivery_option_radio"), function() {
          //console.log($(this)); 
          var idx = obj.carrier + ',';
          if ($(this).val() == idx) {
            console.log(idx);
            $(this).parent('span').addClass('checked');
            $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }), 5000);
```

Doing tests in the Google Chrome console returns this error message:

> VM667:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
>       setTimeout (async)
>       (anonymous) @   shopflores.js:113
>       dispatch    @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
>       r.handle    @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
>       trigger @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
>       e.event.trigger @   jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js:2
>       (anonymous) @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
>       each    @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
>       each    @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
>       trigger @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:3
>       ready   @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2
>       K   @   jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2

I would appreciate your help soon!

Comment: Not sure why this has 4 'unclear what you're asking' votes. The question and code seem pretty straightforward to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout()` expects a function, yet you're providing it with the result of a `$.ajax()` call which is a `jqXHR` object. As such you get the error when JS tries to invoke the object as a function.

To fix this place your AJAX logic within an anonymous function that you provide as the argument to `setTimeout()`:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $.ajax({
    // your AJAX call here...
  })
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.